# Facebook like button bug

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I'm using the facebook like button (both iframe and xfbml), and for some reason facebook strips my URL that ends in this:

`ViewReply.aspx?r=122`

And converts it into this when it posts the 'like' to a wall:

`ViewReply.aspx?r=____%3C%21DOCTYPE+html+PUBLIC`

It even does this when I put the perfectly fine URL into the fb like widget wizard and "like" it.

Any ideas what is going on?  I can't register for the facebook developer forum for some reason (I never receive a signup email) so I figured I'd try here instead.

Thanks.

Comment: post the like button code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has had some issues with extra params on the end of the share links.  I still haven't found an answer but it seems a bug on facebook's part.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<%# Server.UrlEncode(GetAbsoluteUrl(GetDocumentUrl())) %>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```